# Jena JavaScript custom functions scriptEngine null error

Tags: jena, fuseki

**Summary:** I am trying to use the documentation on [JavaScript SPARQL Functions](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/javascript-functions.html) to get a minimal working example of calling a custom javascript function, but it results in a scriptEngine null error.

**Details:** I setup a fuseki environment following the [Docker instructions](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-docker.html), so:

```
docker build --force-rm --build-arg JENA_VERSION=3.16.0 -t fuseki .
```

I then create a `functions.js` file per the documentation on [JavaScript SPARQL Functions](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/javascript-functions.html) and launch the Docker container with:

```
docker run -i --rm -p "3030:3030" --name sparql1 -v `pwd`/functions.js:/functions.js -t fuseki --update --set arq:js-library=/functions.js --mem /ds
```

So far, so good.  I have confirmed this works for simple update and queries, so the container appears sound.  However, if I now create a `query.rq` file containing the [example in the docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/javascript-functions.html):

```
query=PREFIX js: <http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/jsFunction#>

SELECT ?input (js:toCamelCase(?input) AS ?X)
{
  VALUES ?input { "some woRDs to PROCESS" }
}
```

and then proceed to dispatch this query to my container:

```
curl -X POST -d @query.rq localhost:3030/ds/query
```

then the console in which the container is running looks as follows:

```
% docker run -i --rm -p "3030:3030" --name sparql1 -v `pwd`/functions.js:/functions.js -t fuseki --update --set arq:js-library=/functions.js --mem /ds
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          :: Apache Jena Fuseki 3.16.0
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          :: Dataset Type: in-memory
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          :: Path = /ds
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          :: System
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 2.0 GiB
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          ::   Java:   17-ea
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Linux 5.10.76-linuxkit amd64
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          ::   PID:    1
[2022-03-09 16:47:20] INFO  Server          :: Start Fuseki (port=3030)
[2022-03-09 16:47:23] INFO  Fuseki          :: [1] POST http://localhost:3030/ds/query
[2022-03-09 16:47:23] INFO  Fuseki          :: [1] Query = PREFIX js: <http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/jsFunction#>SELECT ?input (js:toCamelCase(?input) AS ?X){  VALUES ?input { "some woRDs to PROCESS" }}
[2022-03-09 16:47:24] WARN  Fuseki          :: [1] RC = 500 : Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(java.io.Reader)" because "scriptEngine" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(java.io.Reader)" because "scriptEngine" is null
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.function.js.JSEngine.build(JSEngine.java:75) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.function.js.JSEngine.<init>(JSEngine.java:61) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.function.js.EnvJavaScript.build(EnvJavaScript.java:103) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.function.js.EnvJavaScript.<init>(EnvJavaScript.java:99) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.function.js.EnvJavaScript.create(EnvJavaScript.java:52) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.function.js.EnvJavaScript.get(EnvJavaScript.java:66) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.E_Function.evalSpecial(E_Function.java:66) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.ExprFunctionN.eval(ExprFunctionN.java:100) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.VarExprList.get(VarExprList.java:106) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterAssign.accept(QueryIterAssign.java:62) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterProcessBinding.hasNextBinding(QueryIterProcessBinding.java:69) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:114) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIterConvert.hasNextBinding(QueryIterConvert.java:58) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:114) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:38) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:114) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorWrapper.hasNextBinding(QueryIteratorWrapper.java:38) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.iterator.QueryIteratorBase.hasNext(QueryIteratorBase.java:114) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetStream.hasNext(ResultSetStream.java:74) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.ResultSetCheckCondition.hasNext(ResultSetCheckCondition.java:55) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQLQueryProcessor.executeQuery(SPARQLQueryProcessor.java:324) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQLQueryProcessor.execute(SPARQLQueryProcessor.java:273) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQLQueryProcessor.executeWithParameter(SPARQLQueryProcessor.java:222) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQLQueryProcessor.execute(SPARQLQueryProcessor.java:207) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionService.executeLifecycle(ActionService.java:58) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.SPARQLQueryProcessor.execPost(SPARQLQueryProcessor.java:83) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionProcessor.process(ActionProcessor.java:34) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionBase.process(ActionBase.java:55) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.ActionExecLib.execAction(ActionExecLib.java:107) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.Dispatcher.dispatchAction(Dispatcher.java:115) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.Dispatcher.process(Dispatcher.java:107) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:101) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.jena.fuseki.servlets.FusekiFilter.doFilter(FusekiFilter.java:51) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) ~[jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) [jena-fuseki-server-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
[2022-03-09 16:47:24] INFO  Fuseki          :: [1] 500 Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(java.io.Reader)" because "scriptEngine" is null (212 ms)
```

It's at this point I'm totally lost ... why would scriptEngine be null here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache Jena 3.16.0, the JS engine was Nashorn. Nashorn was deprecated in Java 11 and removed in Java17.

An earlier Java version will have Hashorn in.

Now Jena version 4.4.0 uses the javascript engine of choice which has been added to the classpath, and hence needs to be in the dockerfile. Jena testing uses GraalVM.

Comment: Super helpful thanks ... this info was instrumental in helping me come up with the solution.  I've added another long-form answer below with full details in case anyone comes across this in future, but have accepted @AndyS answer since that was what helped me solve it!

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the answer by @AndyS above because it helped me solve the problem. For anyone who comes across this and wants to know the full details I'm posting this additional detail.

Basically, I ignored the "official" docker compose script since it uses OpenJDK and instead created a simple Dockerfile based on one of the [official GraalVM containers](https://github.com/graalvm/container). I just needed to add the GraalVM nodejs so that it has a JavaScript interpreter, giving full Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:ol8-java17-22.0.0.2-b2

RUN gu install nodejs

RUN curl -s -S --fail --location --max-redirs 3 https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jena/jena-fuseki-server/4.4.0/jena-fuseki-server-4.4.0.jar --output jena-fuseki-server-4.4.0.jar

RUN adduser -M fuseki

USER fuseki

EXPOSE 3030

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "jena-fuseki-server-4.4.0.jar"]
CMD []
```

Now, you can build this with:

```bash
docker build -t fuseki .
```

And then run it and include the `functions.js` file from the original question with:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -p "3030:3030" --name sparql1 -v $(pwd)/functions.js:/functions.js fuseki --update --set arq:js-library=/functions.js --mem /ds
```

Now, posting the query from the question above gives the correct output:

```bash
% curl -X POST -d @query.rq localhost:3030/ds/query

{ "head": {
    "vars": [ "input" , "X" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      { 
        "input": { "type": "literal" , "value": "some woRDs to PROCESS" } ,
        "X": { "type": "literal" , "value": "someWordsToProcess" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Again, thanks to @AndyS without whose comment this full solution would have evaded me!